# Vuejs bind an array in a v-model

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I would like to bind v-model to an array of values

So i have

```
paymenttypes:[
 {label:'cheque', value:1},
 {label:'two', value:2}
]

pays:[],
created(){
   this.paymentmethods.forEach((value) => {
     this.pays.push({id:value.value, ref: '' , val: 0 })
   });
}
```

now on the template

```
  <div class="row saleTotal" v-for="(key, extrafieldsDetails) in paymentmethods">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h5>{{extrafieldsDetails.label}}</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" min="0" class="text-right form-control" v-model="pays[key].ref">
    </div>
  </div>
```

But am getting an error

```
cannot read property 'ref' of undefined
```

What could be wrong? as the pays array has a object with a key of ref. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: You need to access the object to get the ref

Comment: Thats what i have done,  v-model="pays[key].ref"

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your variables `paymenttypes` and `paymentmethods` are the same.

If so, your `v-for` binding is incorrect. You do not get key-value pairs out of `paymentmethods` because it is an array, **not** an object.

So, your `v-for` could be written as `v-for="(item, index) in paymentmethods"` where `item` is the array item from `paymentmethods`, and `index` is the index of `item` in `paymentmethods`.

Then you would need to replace the property accessors as follows:

- `{{item.label}}` instead of `{{extrafieldsDetails.label}}`
- `pays[index].ref` instead of `pays[key].ref`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    paymentmethods:[
     {label:'cheque', value:1},
     {label:'two', value:2}
    ],

    pays:[]  
  },
  created(){
   this.paymentmethods.forEach((value) => {
     this.pays.push({id:value.value, ref: '' , val: 0 })
   });
   console.log(this.pays);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div class="row saleTotal" v-for="(item, index) in paymentmethods">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h5>{{item.label}}</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" min="0" class="text-right form-control" v-model="pays[index].ref">
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```